# Data conversion from columns to rows

Tags: oracle10g

I have a record `DCP_SC_DOT_TBL` where there are 2 keys `SETID` and `CONTRACTID`. In addition to this this there are 78 more columns which are checkboxes and contain a value `Y` or `Blank`. For example:

```
SETID CONTRACTID  1  2   3 ...... 78  
DCPID  00102      Y      Y
DCPID  00192         Y   Y         Y
```

Now I want to remove all these columns and create a new row for each non-blank column to create a table, for example, like this:

```
SETID CONTRACTID Checkbox(New column for all the 78 columns)
DCPID  00102      1
DCPID  00102      3
DCPID  00192      2
DCPID  00192      3
DCPID  00192      78
```

Can someone please suggest how to achieve this? I want only the column containing some data against the `CONTRACTID`s.

Answer (score 0):

In re-reading your post, it sounds like you simply need a large union query:

```
Select SetId, ContractId, '1' As ColNum, 
From SomeTable As S1
Where S1.Col1 = 'Y'
Union All
Select SetId, ContractId, '2'
From SomeTable As S1
Where S1.Col2 = 'Y'
Union All
Select SetId, ContractId, '3'
From SomeTable As S1
Where S1.Col3 = 'Y'
...
Union All
Select SetId, ContractId, '78'
From SomeTable As S1
Where S1.Col78 = 'Y'
```

If you wanted to result other information from the main table, then you would join this result set to it:

```
Select
From SomeTable As S
        Join    (
                Select SetId, ContractId, '1' As ColNum, 
                From SomeTable As S1
                Where S1.Col1 = 'Y'
                Union All
                Select SetId, ContractId, '2'
                From SomeTable As S1
                Where S1.Col2 = 'Y'
                Union All
                Select SetId, ContractId, '3'
                From SomeTable As S1
                Where S1.Col3 = 'Y'
                ...
                Union All
                Select SetId, ContractId, '78'
                From SomeTable As S1
                Where S1.Col78 = 'Y'
                ) As Z
            On Z.SetId = S.SetId
                And Z.ContractId = S.ContractId
```